# ArrayAdapter<DummyContent.DummyItem> with android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_2

Tags: android, r.java-file

I'm currently using the master / detail flow in my android application project. Now I would like to not only create a list with items with only one string. I'd like to change the standard DummyItem class to the following:

```
     /**
     * A dummy item representing a piece of content.
     */
    public static class DummyItem {
        public String id;
        public String content;
        public String subtext; //Added subtext variable here
        public DummyItem(String id, String content, String subtext) {
            this.id = id;
            this.content = content;
            this.subtext = subtext; //And here
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return content;
        }
    }
```

In the ItemListFragment class I'm having this line of code pre-defined for creating the adapter for the list:

```
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<DummyContent.DummyItem>(getActivity(), 
                   android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1, 
                   android.R.id.text1, 
                   DummyContent.ITEMS));
```

But I would like to change the `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1` to `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_2`

while having `android.R.id.text1` as content and `android.R.id.text2` as my `subtext`-variable.

Is there a possibility to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overwrite the getView() Method of the ArrayAdapter. Should be something like this:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    //super call to create / recycle the view
    View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

    TextView textView1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
    textView1.setText(getItem(position).getContent());

    TextView textView2 = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text2);
    textView2.setText(getItem(position).getSubtext());

    return view;

}
```

Here's some further reading about ListViews, including examples:
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html

Comment: If you set the text of the textViews like I wrote, I don't see, why this should not work... It's not possible to declare multiple textViewResourceIds for the default implementation of ArrayAdapter, but with the overridden getView, you can do this yourself.

Comment: sorry my fault... There was an error in my DummyItem class. Thank you very much for your answer. It really helped a lot!